# Text Box List a jQuery mobile textbox

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, autocomplete, textboxlist

I am building a custom jQuery Mobile auto-complete input box (i.e. no using a plugin) and I want to use a text box list (i.e. display non-text elements inside the text field, see tagging in the Facebook text box for an example). I haven't been able to find any resources on how to approach this. Can anyone point me toward something on how to display non-text elements in a jQuery Mobile input box?

Answer (score 0):

You can put pictures in the listview format, would something like autocomplete displaying a listview of items to choose from with the pictures there work ? also jquery mobile listview has an automatic search bar which dynamically filters results built in already:

Here's the link on all the types of listview possible:

[Jquery-Mobile Listview](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html)

Hope this helps !

In response to your comment It seems that the autocomplete suggestions have to be stored in an array, this can probably be dynamically filled though some request or I you know what the data will be just hard code the suggestions in like this from the jquery ui site:

```
 <script>
        $(function() {
            var availableTags = [
                "ActionScript",
                "AppleScript",
                "Asp",
                "BASIC",
                "C",
                "C++",
                "Clojure",
                "COBOL",
                "ColdFusion",
                "Erlang",
                "Fortran",
                "Groovy",
                "Haskell",
                "Java",
                "JavaScript",
                "Lisp",
                "Perl",
                "PHP",
                "Python",
                "Ruby",
                "Scala",
                "Scheme"
            ];
            $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });
        </script>



    <div class="demo">

    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input id="tags">
    </div>

    </div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description" style="display: none; ">
<p>The Autocomplete widgets provides suggestions while you type into the field. Here the suggestions are tags for programming languages, give "ja" (for Java or JavaScript) a try.</p>
<p>The datasource is a simple JavaScript array, provided to the widget using the source-option.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->
```

does this help ?  you can see more on it here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Sorry to bog you down with the lengthy answer but also the autocomplete can be enhanced to take in pictures see here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data which I think could be along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesn't address what I'm looking for. I'm actually looking to display graphical items inside the text field like in this pic:http://wharsojo.files.wordpress.com/2008/02/jquery_acfb_sc_shoot2.png

Comment: I'm not sure about the images yet but from what I see here the Jquery UI autocomplete widged works fine with jquery mobile so that could be a start : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-widget-with-jquery-mobile

Comment: Good suggestion. I do currently have that implemented, the docs are pretty limited though, haven't figured out a way to control what shows up in the text box.